# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.mx.model.usermgmt.UserDetails

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, fasterxml

I am creating a list of UserDetails in Spring Boot Service class and returning to the Controller class.

In my controller class, when I try to do the following,

```
    List<UserDetails> userList = userManagemetService.getEditableUsersList(user.getUserId());
    System.out.println("userList " + userList + " size " + userList.size());
    System.out.println("userList class 1" + (UserDetails)userList.get(0));
    System.out.println("userList class 2" + userList.get(0).getClass().getName());
```

I get the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.mx.model.usermgmt.UserDetails
```

**UPDATE**

Added method definitions - as can be seen from the definitions, I have not used LinkedHashmap anywhere

```
 public List<UserDetails> getEditableUsersList(String userId) {
      //Get the details of the user
      List<UserDetails> editableUsers = new ArrayList<>();
      try {
         RestResponse<UserDetails> mxUser = this.restFactory.getRestClient(UM_REST_CLIENT_ID)
            .get(RestLocation.withPath(UM_REST_VERSION + UM_REST_USER_RESOURCE).path(userId),
               RestHeaders.empty().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE),
               UserDetails.class);
         if (mxUser.getStatus() == HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
            UserDetails userDetails = mxUser.getEntity();
            System.out.println("mxUserEntity " + userDetails);
            MastersUser mastersUser = userDetails.getmxUser();
            UserREF xrefUser = userDetails.getUserREF();
            System.out.println("mastersUser.getUserId() " + mastersUser.getUserId() + " mastersUser.getUserEmail() " + mastersUser.getUserEmail());
            System.out.println("xrefUser.getRole() " + xrefUser.getRole());
            try {
               ObjectMapper Obj = new ObjectMapper();

               // get Oraganisation object as a json string
               String jsonStr = Obj.writeValueAsString(userDetails);

               // Displaying JSON String
               System.out.println(jsonStr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Check if supervisor
            boolean isSupervisor = isAdmin(xrefUser.getRole());
            //    If true, get the list of all users for all shipto accounts
            if(isSupervisor){
               //Get a list of childShipTo accounts for the user
               List<String> shipToAccounts = getShipToAccountsList(xrefUser.getChildShipToAccounts());
               System.out.println("list of accounts");
               shipToAccounts.forEach(System.out::println);
               List<UserDetails> usersList = shipToAccounts
                                            .stream().map(shipTo -> getUsersForShipTo(shipTo))
                                            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

               editableUsers = usersList;
            }
            //    Otherwise add the user to the list and return
            else{
               editableUsers.add(userDetails);
            }
         }
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
         logger.info("Error fulfilling send credentials request -> ", ioe);
      }

       return editableUsers;
   }


    private List<UserDetails> getUsersForShipTo(String shipTo) {
      List<UserDetails> shipToUsersList  = null;
      try {
         RestResponse<List> shiptoUsers = this.restFactory.getRestClient(UM_REST_CLIENT_ID)
            .get(RestLocation.withPath(UM_REST_VERSION +UM_REST_SHIPTO_USERS_RESOURCE).path(shipTo),
               RestHeaders.empty().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE),
               List.class);
         if (shiptoUsers.getStatus() == HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
            shipToUsersList  = (List<UserDetails>)shiptoUsers.getEntity();
         }
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
         logger.info("Error fulfilling send credentials request -> ", ioe);
      }
      try {
         ObjectMapper Obj = new ObjectMapper();

         // get Oraganisation object as a json string
         String jsonStr = Obj.writeValueAsString(shipToUsersList);

         // Displaying JSON StringusersList
         System.out.println("shipToUsersList " + jsonStr);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return shipToUsersList;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Fix the getEditableUsersList method. It claims it returns a List<UserDetails>, but it actually returns a List of LinkedHashMap. We can't tell why witout the code.

Comment: @JBNizet - added method definitions to the question

Comment: The list ultimately comes from this: `this.restFactory.getRestClient(...).get(..., List.class);`. You're doing a REST call, and tell the rest client to deserialize the body to a List. Without saying that you actually want a List<UserDetails>. So the REST client can't possibly know that you want a list of UserDetails, so it deserializes every element of the list to a LinkedHashMap. Consult the documentation of your REST client (I have no idea what it is) to understand how to tell it to deserialize as a List<UserDetails>.